# Detect vehicle color with image OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, colors, computer-vision

I want to detect vehicle color basing on image. For now i detect if object in image is Car with use of YOLO.

I want to detect color of it and save it to variable called `car_color`. Here is my code:

```py
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import json

image_directory = 'all'
output_directory = 'cars'

# Load YOLO
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3.weights", "yolov3.cfg")
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
    json_data = f.read()

data = json.loads(json_data)
classes = data["payload"]["blob"]["rawLines"]

def crop_image(image, percentage):
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    
    crop_top = int(height * percentage)
    crop_bottom = int(height * (1 - percentage))
    crop_left = int(width * percentage)
    crop_right = int(width * (1 - percentage))
    
    cropped_image = image[crop_top:crop_bottom, crop_left:crop_right]
    
    return cropped_image

for filename in os.listdir(image_directory):
    if filename.endswith('.jpg') or filename.endswith('.png'):
        image_path = os.path.join(image_directory, filename)
        image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        img = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.4)  # Resize image for faster processing
        height, width, channels = img.shape

        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)
        net.setInput(blob)
        outs = net.forward(output_layers)

        for out in outs:
            for detection in out:
                scores = detection[5:]
                class_id = np.argmax(scores)
                confidence = scores[class_id]
                if confidence > 0.5 and classes[class_id] == 'car':
                    # Get car dominant color

                    scale_factor = 0.8
                    car_image = crop_image(image, 1-scale_factor)

                    

                    car_make = filename.split("_")[0]
                    car_model = filename.split("_")[1]
                    car_production_year = filename.split("_")[2]

                    filename = "_".join([car_make, car_model, car_production_year, car_color]) + ".jpg"

                    car_filename = os.path.join(output_directory, filename)
                    cv2.imwrite(car_filename, image)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have extended your code below:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import json
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import webcolors

def find_closest_color(color):
    closest_color = webcolors.rgb_to_name(color)
    return closest_color

def get_dominant_color(image, k=3):
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = image.reshape((image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3))
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
    kmeans.fit(image)
    dominant_color = kmeans.cluster_centers_.astype(int)
    return dominant_color[0]

def crop_image(image, percentage):
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
   
    crop_top = int(height * percentage)
    crop_bottom = int(height * (1 - percentage))
    crop_left = int(width * percentage)
    crop_right = int(width * (1 - percentage))
   
    cropped_image = image[crop_top:crop_bottom, crop_left:crop_right]
   
    return cropped_image

# Rest of your existing code
image_directory = 'all'
output_directory = 'cars'

# Load YOLO
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3.weights", "yolov3.cfg")
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
    json_data = f.read()

data = json.loads(json_data)
classes = data["payload"]["blob"]["rawLines"]

for filename in os.listdir(image_directory):
    if filename.endswith('.jpg') or filename.endswith('.png'):
        image_path = os.path.join(image_directory, filename)
        image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        img = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.4)

        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)
        net.setInput(blob)
        outs = net.forward(output_layers)

        for out in outs:
            for detection in out:
                scores = detection[5:]
                class_id = np.argmax(scores)
                confidence = scores[class_id]
                if confidence > 0.5 and classes[class_id] == 'car':
                    scale_factor = 0.8
                    car_image = crop_image(img, 1 - scale_factor)
                    car_color_bgr = get_dominant_color(car_image)

                    car_color_rgb = (car_color_bgr[2], car_color_bgr[1], car_color_bgr[0])  # Convert BGR to RGB
                    car_color_name = find_closest_color(car_color_rgb)

                    car_make, car_model, car_production_year = filename.split("_")[:3]
                    car_filename = f"{car_make}_{car_model}_{car_production_year}_{car_color_name}.jpg"
                    car_filepath = os.path.join(output_directory, car_filename)
                    cv2.imwrite(car_filepath, car_image)
```

In this code, after successfully identifying a car, it calculates the dominant color of the car using the `get_dominant_color` function (I personally thought that KMeans clustering would be the best fit for this) and then maps the rgb color value to a color name using the `find_closest_color` function. The color information is then incorporated into the output filename for saving the processed car image.

*Note: I have used the webcolors library here to map rgb values to color names but you can also create your own dictionary.*